# Why won't my listview scroll?

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll

Ok so I've looked at other posts with the same problem, but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode",
            "hey Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode",
            "hey Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode",
            "hey Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode",
            "hey Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","end", "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode",
            "hey Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode","Bright Mode", "Normal Mode", "end2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getView().getContext(), R.layout.document_list_view, stringArray);
    list.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Clicking works just fine, but the content goes off screen and it won't let me scroll. Here's my XML. It's not inside a scrollview or anything.

document_list_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:textColor="@color/black">


</TextView>
```

layout of the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1000dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using 1000dp and 600dp? use match_parent on those as well!

Comment: does your class extend `activity` of `fragment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this issue, it was because I was extending a class that places everything inside a scrollview. Don't put listviews inside scrollviews

Answer (score 0):

change your page layout to just be the list view that will match the size of its parent in this case the window decor.

```
<ListView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: can you add a screen shot to you question?  imgur link or similiar image hosting link is ok too.

Comment: a screenshot of the listview? There's not much to see. The content comes up correctly but it's not scrollable. The listview is inside a popup that fills the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom view for each list item, you need to use a Custom Adapter for the list view. You will need something like this

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
List<String> items;
....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.document_list_view, null);
    }

    String item = (String) items.get(position);

    if (item != null) {
        TextView text= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        if (text!= null) {
            text.setText(item);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

And set this object as an adapter to your list.

Comment: if I do this, it becomes blank. Maybe it's not inflating properly?

Comment: Are you setting values for the items list?